# How to store bounding boxes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

When I want to query points within a certain range, I can：

```
CREATE (a:SomeLabel{location:point({x:0,y:0,z:0,crs:'cartesian-3d'})});
MATCH (n) WHERE point({x: -1, y: -1,z:-1}) < n.location < point({x: 2, y: 2,z:2}) RETURN n
```

Now I want to query all bounding boxes in a certain range, and I want to borrow RTREE in neo4j. What kind of syntax can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j has support for spatial values, https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/spatial/#cypher-spatial-specifying-spatial-instants

So for instance, you could calculate distance between 2 points, like so,

```
WITH point({x: 0, y: 0}) AS p1, point({x: 4, y: 4}) as p2 
RETURN distance (p1, p2)
```